# Take users to a link on uninstall chrome packaged app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am developing a chrome packaged app and am trying to set the url for uninstalling the app. I have so far, I have this line on my Background Javascript (or main) for the app:

```
chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(goo.gl/forms/qo8OF2w9pLLyHloa2)
```

But when uninstalled this does nothing? Any help would be loved! Here is my script and it's entirety as well.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('popup.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 640,
      'height': 692
    },
    "resizable": false,
    "frame": {
        color: "#ffffff"
    },
  });
});
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details) {
  console.log("updating to version " + details.version);
  chrome.runtime.reload();
});

chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck(function(status) {
  if (status == "update_available") {
    chrome.runtime.reload();
  } else if (status == "no_update") {
    console.log("no update found");
  }
});

chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL(goo.gl/forms/qo8OF2w9pLLyHloa2)
```

Here is my manifest too

```
{
"name": "Meme Music Board",
"short_name": "Meme Music Board",
"description": "All of your meme songs in one song board. 100+ Songs! You deserve it ;)",
"version":"2.6.4",
"manifest_version": 2,
"author": "Banana Man Development",
"offline_enabled": true,
"app": {
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
"icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png", "48": "icons/icon48.png", "128": "icons/icon128.png" }
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the `manifest.json` file?

Comment: Did you try adding  https to the url

Comment: Yeah I can add it @KevinJohnson
Also yeah one sec

Comment: @The_Grits yeah one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) it states that

> This URL must have an http: or https: scheme.

Try adding `http://` to the front of your url and you should be good to go.

Also make sure to put the url in single quotes, that's what the method requires.

Comment: When i add the http:// it refuses to even launch I'd assume because of the double // in the url

Comment: @CollinWillson Try putting the whole url in single quotes, I'll leave an example in my answer because I can't do it in a comment.

Comment: Okay @The_Grits

Comment: By god it works! Thank you so much @The_Grits You're a god amongst men.

Comment: The documentation says the method requires a string, so I would assume that the url is the problem. I can't seem to put the url in the answer either, Stack Overflow doesn't like url shorteners.

Comment: @CollinWillson Since it works now, can you accept my answer please? (Click the checkmark) Thanks!

Comment: Always, My Pleasure :)